# What is the best practice for phonegap database asynchronous callback functions

Tags: cordova, sqlite

I am using Sqlite in Phonegap Android Application(Like [Storage Samples](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage)).In my Application I have lot of queries which depends on last query result. i know the Phonegap database excuteSql method is Asynchronous. So i make lot of callback functions one after another. Is it correct way to do in large Applications. What is the best practice to use asynchronous callback functions in Phonegap?